# display constants for custom object, similar to MessageBoxButtons

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Ok, so I have an odd question- I'm not sure I'm phrasing this correctly, which may be why I've not found any info on this in my searching.

I have a class defining a Host object representing a computer with various information recorded about that computer.

```
public sealed class Host
{
    public Host(string sName, IPAddress sAddress, string sType, string osName, bool sFirewall)
    {
        Name = sName;
        Address = sAddress;
        Type = sType;
        FirewallActive = sFirewall;
        OperatingSystem = osName;
    }

    public Host()
    {
        Name = "New Host";
        Address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        Type = HostType.Desktop;
        OperatingSystem = HostOS.Win7;
        FirewallActive = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the host
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The ip address of the host
    /// </summary>
    public IPAddress Address { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The type of the host
    /// </summary>
    public string Type { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The operating system the system uses
    /// </summary>
    public string OperatingSystem { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether the system has a firewall enabled
    /// </summary>
    public bool FirewallActive { get; private set; }
}
```

I then have a couple objects with constant values for a couple of the settings.

```
public sealed class HostType
{
    public static string Desktop
    {
        get { return "Desktop"; }
    }
}

public sealed class HostOS
{
    public static string Win7
    {
        get { return "Windows 7"; }
    }
}
```

When I create a new Host object, I want Intellisense to automatically prompt for a "HostOS" variable when I get to that part when constructing a new Hosts([parameters]) object, similar to how when you're using MessageBox.Show(...) it automatically suggests a list of various MessageBoxButtons options when you get to that part of the parameters list.

As in, I don't want to modify the list ever- I just want Intellisense to show me a list of options that are various HostOS constant strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define it as enums rather than classes.

For example:

```
public enum HostType
{
  Desktop,
  Server,
  Laptop
}
```

In the class host you then have to define the property Type as HostType

```
public HostType Type { get; private set }
```